# Wildcard first pathame only in Lumen route

Tags: php, regex, laravel, lumen

Is it possible to wildcard only the first pathname of a route in lumen / laravel? A type of wildcard like this would only work for routes that do not have a proceeding forward slash, for example:

The route path: `/purple` or `/green` would match the wildcard but if the route was prefixed, like `/purple/green` or proceeded with a forward slash, like `/purple/` it would not match the wildcard route.

Currently I am using this wildcard which is matching all routes in the application and conflicting with prefixed and post routes:

```
$router->get('[{name}]', function () use ($router) {
     return view('index');
});
```

From my understanding this can be achieved with Regular Expression matching in Lumen, but how I'm not sure.

Comment: Not as familiar with Lumen, but Laravel's routing is pretty much set up to treat `/purple` and `/purple/` the same.  Using a single route parameter should not touch any routes with additional parts like `/purple/green`

Comment: What do you mean by conflicting? Can you post examples of other routes in conflict and a small list of example routes with the current behavior vs the desired behavior?